# Controls in SceneKit/SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I need help implementing controls to move a SceneKit sphere. I want to have the user touch on the screen and when they move their finger around, the ball will move relative to the position of the user's finger. I don't want the y to increase or decrease I just want x and z, almost like a hula hoop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the GameController Framework seen Apple have released the WWDC Demo 'Fox', and it use GameController to control the character.